# Wildcards in RPZ (response policy zones)

Tags: domain-name-system, rpz

Is it possible to have wildcards domains in the middle of a domain name using response policy zones? For example s3.*.amazonaws.com.

If this is not possible, is there a technology, that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the [QNAME trigger](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-vixie-dnsop-dns-rpz-00#section-4.2) in RPZ has the same wildcard semantics as DNS in general. Ie, it's only when it's specifically the left-most label that is `*` that the asterisk is considered a wildcard.

With RPZ out of the picture, I don't believe there is any standardized interface that does what you ask for, however some DNS server implementations provide some form of implementation-specific policy framework or generic scripting capability.

Here follows some examples of starting points for solutions based on popular free software  (not an exhaustive list, consider these a handful of illustrative examples).

Using some form of policy framework:

- Dnsdist's [RegexRule](https://dnsdist.org/rules-actions.html#RegexRule)
- Knot Resolver's [query policies](https://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules.html#query-policies) (`pattern`)

More low-level solutions based on query interception with generic scripting interfaces:

- Powerdns Recursor's [Lua scripting interface](https://doc.powerdns.com/recursor/lua-scripting/hooks.html)
- Unbound's [python module interface](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/tree/master/pythonmod) (eg their resmod example)

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer.